# Java Sockets: Sending Stdin and GUI data from Client to Server, Server not reading and responding as expected

Tags: java, swing, sockets, stream, stdin

Apologies as I asked something similar last night, but I have narrowed my problem down. I am wondering how to make my Java TCP Socket Server read in the data sent using the printWriter(out) in the Client code from a GUI as it does from the command line stdin.

I have the following classes as an example and everything works fine until the GUI comes into the equation. The data is being sent over to the Server from the GUI as I can echo it on the server side, but it is not being read and parsed properly as the stdin is. Nothing is being sent back to the client. I have tried flushing, using different streams and adding line separators all over the place to no avail. There is also a Protocol class that handles the data on the Server side.

```
public class KnockKnockServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine, outputLine;

    KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
    outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
    out.println(outputLine);

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
         outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
         out.println(outputLine);
         if (outputLine.equals("Bye.")) {
             break;
            }
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

.

```
public class KnockKnockClient {

public static PrintWriter out = null;   
public static String sendAnswer;
public static void Client() {
    //JButton Action Listener
    saveAnswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ButtonModel b = group.getSelection();
                if (b.getActionCommand() == "A") { sendAnswer = radioA.getText(); }
                String data = "รท" + sendAnswer;
                out.println(data);
                }
            });
        }   

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    KnockKnockClient.Client();
    Socket kkSocket = null;
    //PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: localhost.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: localhost.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String fromServer, fromUser;

    while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
        if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
            break;
            fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
    if (fromUser != null) {
            System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
            out.println(fromUser);
        }
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    kkSocket.close();
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty reading your code since it seems to be strangely formatted with random indentation sizes and multiple lines of code and curly braces placed on one line. Please consider fixing this, but your code *appears* to be running roughshod over Swing threading rules. Please improve your code so I can tell for sure if this is the case.

Comment: I tried out your code and inspite of the GUI, the client still seems to be stuck waiting for user input on STDIN. If you give stdin, it does print out the server response.